# How to keep two timers in sync

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I'm still pretty new to coding and Swift. So bear with me.

**Problem Statement :** I've got a stopwatch style app that has two concurrent timers start at the same time and display in a `mm:ss.SS` format, but one is designed to reset to `0` at specific intervals automatically while the other keeps going and tracks total time.

Similar to a "lap" function but it does it automatically. The problem I've encountered is that occasionally the timers aren't perfectly synced up when the user pauses the timers. Since the reset happens at an exact second, both timers should have identical hundredths of a second, while the seconds and minutes will obviously be different. But sometimes the hundredths will be off by .01 or more.

Now, I know Timer isn't designed to be perfectly accurate, and in practice on my app this isn't even a huge deal. My timer doesn't even need to be accurate to the hundredth of a second, and while running it's not noticeably off at all, only while paused. I could display fewer decimal places or none at all, but I prefer the style of showing the hundredths since it fits in well with the stock timer app style.

So if there's a way to make this work, I'd like to keep it.

**Screenshot :** [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fWcM.png)

**What I tried :**

```swift
@IBAction func playPauseTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if timerState == .new {
            //start new timer
            startCurrentTimer()
            startTotalTimer()
            currentStartTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
            totalStartTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
            timerState = .running

            //some ui updates
        } else if timerState == .running {
            //pause timer
            totalTimer.invalidate()
            currentTimer.invalidate()
            timerState = .paused
            pausedTime = Date()
            //other ui updates
        } else if timerState == .paused {
            //resume paused timer
            let pausedInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince(pausedTime!)
            pausedIntervals.append(pausedInterval)
            pausedIntervalsCurrent.append(pausedInterval)
            pausedTime = nil
            startCurrentTimer()
            startTotalTimer()
            timerState = .running
            //other ui updates
        }

    }

    func startTotalTimer() {
        totalTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(runTotalTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func startCurrentTimer() {
        currentTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(runCurrentTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func resetCurrentTimer() {
        currentTimer.invalidate()
        currentStartTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        pausedIntervalsCurrent.removeAll()
        startCurrentTimer()
    }

    @objc func runCurrentTimer() {
        let currentTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

        //calculate total paused time
        var pausedSeconds = pausedIntervalsCurrent.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
        if let pausedTime = pausedTime {
            pausedSeconds += Date().timeIntervalSince(pausedTime)
        }

        let currentElapsedTime: TimeInterval = currentTime - currentStartTime - pausedSeconds

        currentStepTimeLabel.text = format(time: currentElapsedTime)

        if currentElapsedTime >= recipeInterval {
            if recipeIndex < recipeTime.count - 1 {
                recipeIndex += 1

                //ui updates

                //reset timer to 0
                resetCurrentTimer()
            } else {
                //last step
                currentTimer.invalidate()
            }

        }
    }

    @objc func runTotalTimer() {
        let currentTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

        //calculate total paused time
        var pausedSeconds = pausedIntervals.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
        if let pausedTime = pausedTime {
            pausedSeconds += Date().timeIntervalSince(pausedTime)
        }

        let totalElapsedTime: TimeInterval = currentTime - totalStartTime - pausedSeconds

        totalTimeLabel.text = format(time: totalElapsedTime)

        if totalElapsedTime >= recipeTotalTime {
            totalTimer.invalidate()
            currentTimer.invalidate()
            //ui updates
        }
    }

    func format(time: TimeInterval) -> String {
        //formats TimeInterval into mm:ss.SS

        let formater = DateFormatter()
        formater.dateFormat = "mm:ss.SS"

        let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: time)
        return formater.string(from: date)
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a single timer. And when you need a reset to zero, save the current time to a variable.

When presenting the time in the UI, calculate the difference between the running total timer, and the time you saved previously.

Comment: I tried this initially but abandoned it when my code got messy. Also I hadn't thought of saving the current time when resetting to zero and using that. I ended up moving to a single timer, but also made the step timer count down rather than up. Makes for a better UX for the given purpose, and I managed to get it all working. Thanks.